# How to differentiate between the different pronunciations of Merriam-Webster's "ə"

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

This table shows the differences of phonetic symbols between different sources:

| IPA | AHD | MW | Sample Words |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ɝ | û | ə | work, were, bird, dirt, nurse, stir, courage |
| ᴧ | ŭ | ə | but, butt, bud |

[link to the table](http://xahlee.org/wordy/musing/voksa_sinxa_ciste.html)

The two Merriam Webster phonetic symbols are the same, so how am I to know the accurate pronunciation when it appears in a new word?

Comment: Please link to where you found that. The column headings might be relevant and we need to be able to judge how to interpret the quality of the source.

Comment: The same vowel in *bird* and *courage* suggests a specific accent, and not one I'm used to

Comment: Presumably they're saying that MW only has *one* symbol, and doesn't distinguish those two vowels.

Comment: Do note that vowel sounds are highly dependent on the speaker's upbringing and education.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your last question first: Use a dictionary that follows a widely-accepted standard; that's what IPA is for.  If you really want to use Merriam-Webster's pronunciation guidance, you'll need to refer to [their own notes](https://assets2.merriam-webster.com/mw/static/pdf/help/guide-to-pronunciation.pdf).

Going back to the source of your table: I wouldn't trust it. There's a lot wrong with that page, which  appears to be just a personal opinion.  In particular the author has ignored the distinction between \ə\ and \ər\ in the M-W guide.

I think the examples are the author's own, and I don't think the author is a native speaker of a common dialect of English.  Some examples only make sense in a rhotic accent (seemingly treated as default by Merriam-Webster), while others don't make sense in the same accent.

Some examples:

- [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/work) has /wəːk/, not the /wɝk/ implied.
- [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work) has \ˈwərk. We can't neglect the *r* in that transcription as the author of the page you linked does (see p.2 of the pronunciation notes I linked in my first paragraph).
- As I commented, *courage* doesn't belong in the first list, in (most) English or many American accents:

  - [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/courage): /ˈkʌrɪdʒ/ would put it in the *second* list (ʌ).
  - [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/courage) gives two pronunciations: \ˈkər-ij , ˈkə-rij\ of which the first does fit the ɝ list.  But the second fits the ʌ list.  The notes under \ˈər-, ˈə-r\ in the pdf I linked make this clearer.
  - As such a poor example for either list, including it at all is misleading.

Comment: In General American, *courage* and *curry* have the same first syllable. I think most of the asker's confusion has to do with not knowing to analyse phonemic /r/ as a consonant.

Comment: @tchrist they share the first syllable in British English too (a definite /ʌ/ though).  I suspect you're right about phonemic /r/, but I think the OP has been confused by a confused author, or to put it another way both are relying too much on a misreading of the M-W transcription.

Comment: There isn’t actually one single standard IPA transcription for English, either. It’s always a good idea to look at the dictionary’s pronunciation guide.

Comment: @sumelic of course.  The difference as I see it is that if you follow another dictionary's IPA guide (or Wikipedia's, or a half-recalled combination supplemented by spot-checks) you'll be close, but if you try to interpret M-W's pronunciations using anything other than their own guide you'll get very confused.

Answer (score 2):

That table is a bit inaccurate: IPA’s /ɝ/ matches \ər\, not \ə\, in MW.

That being said, in MW, \ə\ does stand for both /ə/ and /ʌ/, which is not a problem for most American English speakers, who don’t distinguish those sounds anyway. However, the phonetic guide PDF that’s on MW’s website explains that \ə\ is /ʌ/ when it either has primary or secondary stress, but /ə/ otherwise.

- append = /əˈpɛnd/ = \ə-ˈpend\
- upend = /ʌpˈɛnd/ = \ˌəp-ˈend\

Pretty much the same thing goes for \ər\ standing for both /ɝ/ and /ɚ/; most American English speakers do not pronounce “forward” any differently from “foreword”.

- forward = /ˈfɔːrwɚd/ = \ˈfȯr-wərd\
- foreword = /ˈfɔːrˌwɝd/ = \ˈfȯr-(ˌ)wərd\